# Images that dynamically loaded from web url are invisible at load

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmapimage, gridpanel

I'm using dynamically loaded images for background of my grid elements in ItemsControl's DataTemplate

```
<ItemsControl Name="Category_Items" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Margin="10" Name="WrapPanel" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Cursor="Hand" Margin="4,0,4,8" Width="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, ElementName=WrapPanel, Path=ActualWidth, ConverterParameter='0,25'}"
                                                           Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},ConverterParameter='0,6'}">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Logo, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,5"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

as you can see my grid elements width and height properties are determined by WrapPanel's actual width and its own height.

I'm using below Converter Class to get image's uri and load it from web.

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.UriSource = new Uri(value as string, UriKind.Absolute);
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
        image.EndInit();
        return image;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

it seems the work fine. But the images are invisible at load. After dragging or resizing the main window make the images appear.

**UPDATE**
Here is the UI, I try to build.
[image: Here is the UI, I try to build.]

I tried to refresh the user control after load. But it didnt help.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You don't need that converter. WPF has built-in automatic type conversion from Uri and string to ImageSource.

Comment: Could you add some details about the layout you are trying to achieve? It looks strange to bind the Grid dimensions in the DataTemplate to a fraction of the dimensions of the ItemTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens, you are right. I changed the ImageSource property to "{Binding Logo}", but the problem remains same.

Comment: @Clemens, i updated my question with the image of UI that I try to build.

Comment: I'd suggest to remove the Width and Height bindings in the DataTemplate and replace the WrapPanel by a UniformGrid. UniformGrid allows you to specify a fixed number of rows or columns. You would then put the ItemsControl in a Grid to make it stretch in both directions.

Comment: I thought that but number of rows or columns are not fixed. Items of ItemsControl element would be multiplied.

Comment: Doesn't `ConverterParameter='0,25'` mean that you have four columns? Apparently you still haven't provided enough information to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82099/discussion-between-volkan-kahyaoglu-and-clemens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours of struggling, i gave up to use the image as grid's background. Instead, I used Image Element and everything worked well.

```
<ItemsControl Name="Category_Items" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Margin="10" Name="WrapPanel" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid ClipToBounds="True" Cursor="Hand" Margin="4,0,4,8" Width="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, ElementName=WrapPanel, Path=ActualWidth, ConverterParameter='0,333'}"
                                                           Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},ConverterParameter='0,6'}">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Logo, IsAsync=True}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                    <lib:TextPath Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,5" FontSize="22" Fill="White" Stroke="Black" FontWeight="Bold"/>                        
                    <Grid.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding GetCompanies}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"></MouseBinding>
                    </Grid.InputBindings>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```